# How to click and close the banner after accessing the website https://www.aliexpress.com/ using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriverwait, aliexpress

I'm trying to access a well known online shopping service, to filter and sort results, however the service has a "popup" offering coupons when you first open the site. I'm trying to dismiss the message. The problem is the popup, isn't a real popup, it's a series of div and img tags which are dynamically created shortly after visiting the homepage.

I've tried searching by class, Xpath, CSS but no luck. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, executable_path='chromedriver')
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get('https://www.aliexpress.com/')

timeout = 30

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="6216442440"]/div/div/img')))
except TimeoutException:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element to dismiss the message is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.aliexpress.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://campaign.aliexpress.com/wow/gcp/']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.rax-image[src^='https://img.alicdn.com/tfs']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.aliexpress.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://campaign.aliexpress.com/wow/gcp/')]")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@class='rax-image ' and starts-with(@src, 'https://img.alicdn.com/tfs')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: aliexpress_deals]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: Nice one! I missed the part where it was in an iframe.

Comment: took a little break from [selenium] was trying to answer [python] questions.... but those are hard lol

Comment: @Jortega Stay tuned, I'm in the process of creating the Selenium chat room. See you there.

Comment: Count me in!  (adding extra characters to meet min length requirement)

Comment: Thanks for that, think I spent most of yesterday afternoon bashing my head on that one.